# Solving a non-linear equation in python

Tags: python, error-handling, sympy, nonlinear-equation

```
from sympy import Eq, Symbol, solve

v = Symbol('v')
eqn = Eq(0.55**1.3*((3.91/v)-0.01162)*(0.02472*(v-5)+1.132), 0.0)

x = solve(eqn)
print(x)
real_x = [val for val in x if val > 0] 
print(real_x)
```

NotImplementedError: Unanticipated argument of Eq when other arg is True or False.

What is the actual problem in this code?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Python 3.8.6

Comment: Dito. It works for me, too. Python 3.8 and 3.7

Comment: What sympy version are you using? Latest version is 1.7.1 and this example works there.